# What does "it" in "What's it like" refer to?

Tags: meaning, pronouns, antecedents

In *Memento* (2000), Burt speaks to Leonard:

> That's the thing. I have this condition.
>
> BURT Condition?
>
> LEONARD I have no memory.
>
> BURT Amnesia?
>
> LEONARD No. It's different. I have no short-term memory. I know who I
> am and all about myself, but since my injury I can't make any new
> memories. Everything fades. If we talk for too long, I'll forget how
> we started. I don't know if we've ever met before, and the next time I
> see you I won't remember this conversation. So if I seem strange or
> rude, that's probably...
>
> He notices that Burt is staring at him as if he were an exotic insect.
>
> LEONARD (cont'd) I've told you this before, haven't I?
>
> BURT (nods) I don't mean to mess with you. It's just so weird. You
> don't remember me at all, and we talked a bunch of times.
>
> Leonard shrugs.
>
> BURT (cont'd) What's the last thing you remember?
>
> Leonard looks through Burt, thinking.
>
> LEONARD My wife.
>
> BURT (fascinated) What's **it** like?
>
> LEONARD Like waking. Like you always just woke up.

What does "it" in "What's it like" refer to?

Comment: Probably "the experience of remembering".  (Or "not remembering", given what movie this is.)

Comment: We need more context. The preceding dialogue or delivery probably make it clear.

Comment: OP, you do know that dialog is highly context-dependent, right? I'm afraid you're going to hate the rest of this movie if you're running into these problems early on. Maybe you should try reading something easier first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Burt: What's the last thing you remember?
> Leonard: My wife.
> Burt: What's **it** like?

One thing is certain, the pronoun *it* does not refer to Leonard's wife, which requires the feminine pronoun *she*.

- “What's she like?”.
- “What is *your wife* like?”

This is further confirmed by Leonard's response

> It's like waking. It's like you just woke up.

If "it" referred to his wife that description makes no sense whatsoever. So to find the [antecedent](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/pronouns/pronoun-antecedent.html) we must look further back to the beginning of the conversation between Burt and Leonard.

> LEONARD: That's the thing. I have this **condition**.

```
            BURT
    Condition?

            LEONARD
    I have no memory.

            BURT
    Amnesia?

            LEONARD
    No. It's different. I have no short-term
    memory. I know who I am and all about
    myself, but since my injury I can't make
    any new memories. Everything fades. If we
    talk for too long, I'll forget how we
    started. I don't know if we've ever met
    before, and the next time I see you I
    won't remember this conversation. So if I
    seem strange or rude, that's probably...
```

> LEONARD: (cont'd)
> I've told you **this** [*the short term memory loss*] before, haven't I?

```
            BURT
       (nods)
    I don't mean to mess with you. It's just
    so weird. You don't remember me at all,
    and we talked a bunch of times.
```

Source: [The Internet Movie Script Database (IMSDb)](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Memento.html)

Thus "it" in Burts' question refers to Leonard's short-term memory loss.

- What's *[a/an [extremely] **short-term memory***] like?
- What's this **condition** like?

The expression *short-term memory* is the **headword** of the noun phrase, the words *extremely* and *this* are called **premodifiers** because they modify the headword that follows. The use of "it” makes it a placeholder for the entire noun phrase.

There is another way of interpreting Burt's question, the *post modifying clause* is omitted entirely, as shown below in what is known as an **[elliptical sentence](http://https:/http://the-language-cru.blogspot.com/2013/05/elliptical-sentences.html)**.

- **What's it like** [*to have short term memory*]?